# Random sampling of consumer IDs over time that allows entry of new consumers

Tags: time-series, sampling, panel-data, research-design

I have a Dataset of consumers over 20 months.  Each consumer is identified with a unique ID of four digits, which can be 0-9 except for the first character, assigned upon entry. Each month, some consumers either become deceased or drop out of the data and new consumers enter the data for the first-time.

If I want a small sample of consumers, retaining those sampled at month 0 throughout the time frame, while still capturing new entries in later months, I can select IDs by fixing the last 2 digits in the sequence like 'XX49' (although I don't think it's close to random and the result doesn't necessarily represent the full sample).

Let's assume now that the Dataset is very large and each consumer simply has some unique ID that is not randomly assigned. What if I want a true random sample of 1%, that keeps the consumers sampled in month 0 until they drop out, while allowing new consumers to enter so that each month I always have a representative 1% sample of the data that follows the life cycle of the consumers I capture. How would I do this? And is there a name for this type of sampling when doing survey analysis, economic research, or building predictive models?

Comment: Read about stratified sampling and see if that is what you are looking for. Idea is to categorise population in subpopulations and then drawing samples from these to ensure each subpopulation is represented in the sample.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. I suppose it's like each month, these consumers may fall into specific score bands, age groups, etc. And I would ensure representation of these groups as people die/transition groups with new entrants through reweighting? I'll read up on this.